# How to prove a zero mean martingale converges almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The specific description is following:

Let {${X_n}$} be  a  martingale satisfying $EX_1=0$ and $EX_n^2<\infty$ for all $n$. Show that $E(X_{n+m}-X_n)^2=\sum_{j=1}^mE(X_{n+j}-X_{n+j-1})^2$ and {$X_n$} converges almost surely.

P.S.: It's almost trivial to show $E(X_{n+m}-X_n)^2=\sum_{j=1}^mE(X_{n+j}-X_{n+j-1})^2$ and one can move on to show {$X_n$} converges a.s. if it's $L^
2$-bounded. But the conditions include only $EX_n^2<\infty$ for all $n$, not $L^2$-bounded. How can I reach the a.s. convergence?

Comment: Can you say where this problem comes from?  I wonder if there is some context you have omitted, or if the problem is simply wrong.  As Kavi's answer shows, the statement as written is false.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sure. This is an exercise problem from $Mathematical Statistics $ 2nd edition by Jun Shao(2003). Page 85, Exercise 110. Basically I’m copying the description.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is very very unlikely that such an exercise exists in the book. Please go back to the book and check the statement. If this is indeed what the book says then the author has made a serious mistake.

Comment: I have re-edited the problem so it’s exactly the same as the original exercise stated. Also I’ve sent a mail to author himself to confirm. Once I have an answer I’ll post it here. Anyway thank you both for your help.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I can confirm that this is what the exercise says.  So it seems indeed to be an error in the book.  Perhaps the author meant to assume $\sup_n EX_n^2 < \infty$ which would make the claim true.

Answer (score 3):

Thus is false. Let $\{Y_i\}$ be i.i.d. taking values $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each and $X_n=Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n$. Then $\{X_n\}$ is a martingale, $EX_n=0$ for all $n$ and $EX_n^{2} <\infty$ for all $n$ but this martingale does not converge almost surely. If it does converge then the series $\sum Y_n$ converges  almost surely which implies $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely. But $|Y_n|=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks. But something remains to be discussed here. Your example is so-called Rademacher distribution. It looks to me that $X_n$ converges a.s. to some $X$ but the analytic form of which is difficult to show. We can check if $X_n$ converges in $L_p$, which implies that $X_n$ converges in probability. Then by Theorem 5.3.4 on Chung(2001), Page 126, $X_n$ converges a.s.

Comment: @BigRemy: It is not true that $X_n$ converges in $L_p$.  Would you like to explain why you think it does?  We might be able to help you find the problem in your reasoning.  Also, Kavi's argument that it does not converge a.s. is perfectly correct.

Comment: @NateEldredge I’m not sure whether $X_n$ converges in $L_p$, just considering a path to a.s. convergence. I think we may have a  misunderstanding about “convergence” here. It’s not a number that $X_n$ will converge to, but a random variable.

Comment: @BigRemy If $X_n=Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$ converges to some random variable then (whatever be the limiting RV we must have $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely. This  basic fact from Calculus is trivial to prove: $Y_n=(Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n)-(Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_{n-1})=X_n-X_{n-1}$. In my example it is not true that $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely. Does this clarify your doubts?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This is exactly what I’m questioning about your argument. If $X_n$ actually converges to some r.v., say $X$, $Y_n$ doesn’t have to converge to zero. If we change your setting to an i.i.d Bernoulli sequence, then the sum of this sequence converges to a discrete part of Normal distribution. However, the Bernoulli member of this sequence doesn’t converge to zero. In fact, sum of the sequence to be unbounded is allowed, because the limit r.v. $X$, as a function, can be unbounded.

Comment: @BigRemy Your confusion is very strange.  If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum a_n$ converges the  $a_n \to 0$. The argument holds for almost sure convergence of random variables because almost sure convergence of $\sum X_n$  is nothing but convergence  of the series of real numbers $\sum X_n(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ outside some set of probability $0$.